# How to use amazon certificate to get https on domain route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have an AWS EC2 instance, a Route53 registered domain, an AWS Load Balancer and an AWS Certificate.

What I want to achieve is to access the domain as "https://...", as of today  I haven't been able to.

What I've done so far is:

1.- Set the EC2 (Amazon Linux AMI) with apache and it's listening to de ports :80 :443

When I browse to the puclic IP of the EC2 I see index.html no problem.

2.- I have registered a new domain using Route53. I added a Record Set for the Hosted Zone Type IPv4 address with the value of the IP of the EC2 instance.

When I browse to the domain.com I see index.html no problem.

3.- I got an AWS Certificate for *.domain.com and domain.com. For validation I added a Type CNAME Record Set provided to the Hosted Zone of the domain. For both the validation status is OK.

4.- I created a Load Balancer that listens to HTTP:80 and HTTPS:443 and I added a Record Set in the Hosted Zone of the domain with [type:IPv4, Alias:Yes, Alias Target: name of the Load Balancer]. I didn't type the name of the Load Balancer, I selected it from the select dropdown.

However the Load Balancer has the fields Port Configuration and Instance Count blank as you can see in the screenshot.

[image: Load balancer]

5.- When I check the file /etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error_log I see a message that I can'f figure out what it means, nothing good I imagine. The text of the message is AH01906: ... as you can see in the next screenshot.

[image: ssl error log]

When I browse to https:// domain I get the message that is not safe.

I'm very new to all this and I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out what.

I would appreciate any help or pointer you could give to me.

Thanks very much, this community is awesome anyway.

Comment: Unless you have also obtained a separate SSL certificate from some other means than AWS, and installed that SSL certificate on your EC2 server, you shouldn't be messing with SSL and port 443 on the EC2 instance at all. Just configure all listeners on the load balancer to forward to port 80 on the EC2 instance. The ACM SSL certificate is on the load balancer, not the EC2 server.

Comment: Thanks! Mi error was in a Recordset in the Route53. I added a type A recordset with value the IP of the EC2 instance and I guess that made the balancer to not work properly. I've taken it out and only left the recordset for the Balancer and it's working fine.

Comment: If you pointed the record set directly to the EC2 instance it didn't "make the load balancer not work properly" it entirely bypassed the load balancer and sent all traffic directly to the EC2 instance.

Comment: That's what I meant, but you are absolutely right. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

AWS Certificate Manager does not offer free SSL for website. It does offer free SSL certificate for some of their `services endpoint` (not the same as using directly on your EC2 instance).

For certificates that you want to install directly on EC2, you have to pay for a private Certificate Authority. (note: its expensive)

```
Q: With which AWS services can I use ACM certificates?

You can use public and private ACM certificates with the following AWS services:
• Elastic Load Balancing – Refer to the Elastic Load Balancing documentation
• Amazon CloudFront – Refer to the CloudFront documentation
• Amazon API Gateway – Refer to the API Gateway documentation
• AWS Elastic Beanstalk – Refer to the AWS Elastic Beanstalk documentation
• AWS CloudFormation – Support is currently limited to public certificates that use email validation. Refer to the AWS CloudFormation documentation  

In addition, you can use private certificates issued with ACM Private CA with EC2 instances, containers, IoT devices, and on your own servers.
```

Alternatively, you can use Let's Encrypt, a service provided by EFF, for free. They have a tool called CertBot to automatically renew the certificates for you.